# Where does the standard specify that functions defined inside a class are inline?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, member-functions, one-definition-rule

In my understanding, member functions defined inside a class definition are implicitly `inline`:

```
class X {
  int f() { return 1; } // Implicitly inline.
};
int g() { return 2; } // Not implicitly inline.
```

I was looking for the standard quote to support this, but I can only find [basic.link/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#7):

> In addition, a member function, static data member, a named class or enumeration of class scope, or an unnamed class or enumeration defined in a class-scope typedef declaration such that the class or enumeration has the typedef name for linkage purposes ([[dcl.typedef]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef)), has the same linkage, if any, as the name of the class of which it is a member.

I can't find anything relevant in [dcl.typedef](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.typedef) that relates to simple class definitions (without `typedef` being involved).

Am I looking in the right place? If not, what and where is the exact standard wording?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps look in the section about, well, `inline`.

> [`[dcl.inline]/4:`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.inline#4) A function defined within a class definition is an inline function.

This is actually repeated later, in the section about member functions (which also seems sensible!):

> [`[class.mfct]/1:`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mfct#1) A member function may be defined in its class definition, in which case it is an inline member function *[..]*

Comment: @SombreroChicken Never said it didn't make sense!

Comment: Didn't cross my mind to check the section about the specifier when I'm looking for the case where the specifier is not needed. But I guess I could've taken a look at `[class.mfct]` indeed...

Answer (score 4):

It's in [[class.mfct]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mfct#1):

> A member function may be defined in its class definition, in which case it is an inline member function, ...